# DBI::DatabaseError: Access denied for user error When connect the remote Mysql Server use Ruby DBI

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dbi

Here is my sample code for using DBI:

```
db = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:database=testdatabase;host=testhost;port=30012", "testuser", "testpassword")
```

It returned, and looks no problem:

```
#<DBI::DatabaseHandle:0x00000001c7f0f0 @handle=#<DBI::DBD::Mysql::Database:0x00000001c9f148 @handle=#<Mysql:0x00000001ca6678>, @attr={"AutoCommit"=>true}, @have_transactions=true, @mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000001c813f0>>, @trace_output=nil, @trace_mode=nil, @convert_types=true, @driver_name="Mysql">
```

And then I call the "prepare" method:

```
sql = "select * from users where id in (?)"
dbh = db.prepare(sql)
```

And it also looks ok(The follow code is just a part of the return):

```
#<DBI::StatementHandle:0x00000005e404a8 @handle=#<DBI::DBD::Mysql::Statement:0x00000005e42118 @attr={}, @mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000001c813f0>, @handle=#<Mysql:0x00000001ca6678>, @parent=#<DBI::DBD::Mysql::Database:0x00000001c9f148 @handle=#<Mysql:0x00000001ca6678>, @attr={"AutoCommit"=>true}, @have_transactions=true, @mutex=#<Mutex:0x00000001c813f0>>
```

But when I use "execute" method:

```
dbh.execute('1,2,3')
```

Then it occur error:

```
DBI::DatabaseError: Access denied for user 'testuser'@'120.120.120.120' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: I can use the command login the mysql console: mysql -uusername -p -h hostname -P port_name. And the above code is normal in my localhost.

Comment: Just a wild guess,  you are setting a different password with remote and localhost

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes, the localhost and remote password is different, I used the remote password when I connect the remote mysql server, and the above code being tested in the rails console(production). when I directly login mysql console, it is no problem, just use DBI execute have this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I mistook the direction of the question, Actually, The cause of the problem is the "into outfile" method privileges. It need Mysql open "file" privileges. Like this:

```
grant file on *.* to 'username'@'hostname';
```